# Sending data between 2 windows forms of which one is singleton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have following problem i have 2 windows forms and to send data between them i figured out that in Form2(which is called by Form1) constructor i will be passing reference to Form1 .

Like this `public Form2(Form callingForm)
        {
            mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }`

But I would like Form2 to be singleton and somehow I don't know how to achieve that along with passing form1's reference to form2. I reviewed documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx and I have no clue how to edit this example to fit my needs. So I am able to make singleton constructor or make constructor that takes reference to form1, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

If Form1 is your application's Main Form then you should use --> `Appliction.MainForm`. That way you don't need the parameter.

**Edit:** I was not trying to be obtuse and not answer your question. You can create a singleton with parameters using multiple constructors, however, I would try to avoid it.

```
private Singleton(param1,param2) 
public static Singleton MyInstance(param1,param2)
```

Comment: thank you, Application.OpenForms[0] solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understand your question very well, but I think, you can implement Lazy.. (Lazy itself implements Singleton pattern). Maybe something like this:

```
class Form1
{
  public Form2 Callee
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public Form1()
  {
    Callee = Form2.Instance(this).Value;
  }
}

class Form2
{
  public static Lazy<Form2> Instance(Form1 caller)
  {
    return new Lazy<Form2>(() =>
    {
        return new Form2(caller);
    });
  }

  public Form1 Caller
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  Form2(Form1 caller)
  {
    Caller = caller;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i seem to have solved this problem, here is the code:

```
 private Form1 mainForm = null;
public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Form2(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

@lrb thank you, basically i had problem in this line, cuz couldn't pass anything as parameter

```
instance = new Form2(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1);
```

and Application.OpenForms[0] helped.